# Exclude_id field when updating into mongodb at C#

Tags: c#, mongodb-query

I have written this command for updating my document:

```
collection.UpdateOne(l => l.Topic == topic, update, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });
```

but I got this error from mongodb::

```
{"A write operation resulted in an error.\r\n  After applying the update to the document {_id: BinData(4, 1477ECCA232C438B9E2C29E8305B81AF) , ...}, the (immutable) field '_id' was found to have been altered to _id: BinData(4, A1625EE801F54BCEA2E662A75CF2A164)"}
```

I know that I can not update `_id field` but how can I do some work that when update time  _id field To be Excluded?

*********** Edit ***********

```
            var update = Builders<FinalLocation>.Update
        .Set("Id", location.Id)
       .Set("Lat", location.Lat)
       .Set("Lng", location.Lng)
       .Set("CreationDateTime", location.CreationDateTime)
       .Set("DeviceId", location.DeviceId)

       .Set("Topic", location.Topic)
       .Set("UserId", location.UserId)
       .Set("UserName", location.UserName)
       .Set("DeviceIdId", location.DeviceIdId)

       .Set("Data", location.Data)
       .Set("FirstName", finalLocation.FirstName)
       .Set("LastName", finalLocation.LastName)
       .Set("AllowDomains", finalLocation.AllowDomains)
       .Set("JobLocationName", finalLocation.JobLocationName);
```

Comment: I believe you must remove from the data involved in the update.

Comment: are not there any way to update collection?

Comment: could you show us an example on how your "update" variable is defined?

Comment: @MarioVernari my post updated.

Comment: There's no "_id" in your snippet: how is you get an error? Anyway, since you explicitly build the data, you always can control what's involved and what's not. However, I can't help you if you'll leverage the Entity Framework or any similar reflection-based serialization.

Comment: `.Set("Id", location.Id)` is converted to the Mongo.Ok dude.thnks

Comment: Glad to know that: I wasn't aware about this implicit naming fallback. Good luck